# Module exporting with prototypes and export inheritance in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some questions about module exporting and their inheritance in node.

I know you can export a module with

```
module.exports = function User(){
   // Lot of code
}
```

But, how could you add prototypes functions and get them exported as well? Is this automatic?

For example will this code be available to the exported user?

```
User.prototype.login = function (password) {
     // Much more code
}
```

And finally, if I require moduleA and moduleB in the main script, will be able moduleB to use those objects or should I require it as well? What route should be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's automatic, you don't need to do any magic, but I recommend you do `module.exports = User;` at the end of the file.

If you need moduleB to include something from moduleA you can either:

- require moduleA inside moduleB
- pass moduleB a parameter representing the object / function from module A when requiring it.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. By the way, you can also upvote accepted answers on stackoverflow. Cheers